# Spring boot JPA filter by join table

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I cant find something concrete in the docs (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) 
and no satisfying answere in several blogs.
so here my question.

I have table Entity like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "workstation")
public class Workstation
{
 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name = "userid", nullable = false)
 public User user;
}
```

And the user table Entity:

```
public class user
{
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
 @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
 public Integer id;

 @Column(name = "age", nullable = false)
 public int age
}
```

Now I would like to have a query in my Repository like this:

```
public interface WorkstationRepo extends CrudRepository<Workstation, Long> {
 findByUserAgeLesserThan(int maxAge);
}
```

Means I want to find all user who are under a certain age through my Workstation Entity.

And is it possible without a @Query annotation? Or/And how should it look like?

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
List<Workstation> findByUserAgeLessThan(int maxAge);
```

Alternatively you can also write your query

```
@Query("Select w from Workstation w where w.user.age < :maxAge")
List<Workstation> findByUserAgeLesserThan(@Param("maxAge") int maxAge);
```

Comment: Well, the first option didnt work so good. It makes Problems more complex Names. e.g. if us use "AllUsers" and "TrueAge" Spring cant look up for it.

Comment: Whats the problem with the first option? I tested it locally and it worked pretty decently.

Comment: yes the query method names gets really complicated and lengthy when there is a little complex query involved. Your best option as of now would be to use `@Query()`

Comment: Yes! It worked well for clean small Names, But for more CamelCase Names: it transforms it in a strange way. If I would have a better Documentation for it I ll would use it straigth ahead :) I Love That Spring JPA! Even it seems a bit "hacky" :)

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
@Query("SELECT w from Workstation w INNER JOIN w.user u where u.age < ?1")
List<Workstation> findByUserAgeLessThan(int age);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT w from Workstation w INNER JOIN w.user u where u.age < :age")
List<Workstation> findByUserAgeLessThan(@Param("age") int age);
```

Basically, you need to `JOIN` the tables using `JPQL`.

Comment: Thanks! So using Query by hand seems to be the most obvious right now :)

Comment: But the **@Param** seems deprecated.... so using in query "?1" for the first variable helps.